# How do I make the feed button pop up in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My horses are hungry but I don’t know how to feed them because the only way the feed button pops up is when I hit them.

Is there another way to feed them without hurting the horses?

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki you can simply hold an applicable food type in your hand and right click the horse to feed it.

> To feed a horse, hold a valid food item and right click on the horse.
> If the food is invalid, the player will simply mount the horse. Horses
> can only be fed when feeding would have an effect, similar to other
> animals.

Valid food types are : Sugar, Wheat, Apple, Golden Carrot, Golden Apple, Hay Bale.

---

EDIT

Just noticed the pocket edition tag.

- For Java Edition (PC/Mac), right click on the horse.
- For Pocket Edition (PE), you move your pointer over the horse and press the Feed button.
- For Xbox 360 and Xbox One, press the LT button on the Xbox controller.
- For PS3 and PS4, press the L2 button on the PS controller.
- For Wii U, press the ZL button on the gamepad.
- For Nintendo Switch, press the ZL button on the controller.
- For Windows 10 Edition, right click on the horse.
- For Education Edition, right click on the horse.

Note : A horse will only eat food if its health bar is down or if it is a baby horse that is growing. If you try to feed a horse otherwise, it will not eat the food.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse)
[Source2](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/how_to_feed_horse.php)